# python program incorrect output about function

Tags: python

```
def slove(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
        totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks
        if totLegs == numLegs:
            return [numPigs, numChicks]
        return [None, None]
```

I want to calcuate a number of numPigs and numChicks.
I input slove(20,56), but the answer is None None.
Could you tell me what's wrong with my program?

Comment: put return [None,None] outside for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work !

```
def slove(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
        totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks
        if totLegs == numLegs:
            return [numPigs, numChicks]
    return [None, None]
```